# Linux "stress" tool

Tags: linux, memory, testing

I have seen one of the trick to use 90% of the available system memory with following command :

```
stress --vm-bytes $(awk '/MemFree/{printf "%d\n", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)k --vm-keep -m 1.
```

What I understood till now is : /proc/meminfo is returning available system RAM.

**Can anyone please help me understand what this command is doing?**

Answer (score 1):

`/proc/meminfo` returns all kinds of memory information including:

```
MemTotal:        3996276 kB
MemFree:         1052516 kB
Buffers:          183884 kB
Cached:           949892 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
```

A typical line consists of three columns:

- $1 = MemFree:
- $2 = 1052516
- $3 = kB

The `awk` command is performing the following actions:

1. filters for the specific entry `MemFree`: `'/MemFree/'`
2. calculates 90 % of `MemFree` value: `$2 * 0.9`
3. prints the calculated value followed by a newline: `printf "%d\n"`

The result of the command `$(awk '/MemFree/{printf "%d\n", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)` will return a value like `933357` (based on the MemFree value above).

Finally the `stress` command is instructed to allocate that amount of memory in kilobytes (note the `k` after the `$(..)`).

For additional information on the `stress` parameters, read http://linux.die.net/man/1/stress

Comment: thanks for the link info.I was going through it and One  thing i am not getting is how Long this command will run and  if i will make later part of this command --vm-keep -m 2 then it must throw an error?because with -m 1 option this will launch 1 process which is going to use 90% of the free memory then m 2 must give some error thet insufficient memory, but it is not happening.why so?

Comment: Indefinitely, unless you specify a timeout using the `-t` parameter, for example: `-t 10` to run it for 10 seconds.

Comment: My first quess about the two workers is that you are 'playing' with 90% of ***free*** memory. Imagine that you have 4GB of total memory, with some applications running you have 512MB Free memory left. You will be playing with 900MB of memory using the `stress` utility. It might be the case that other applications can be swapped out so `stress` utility can get the requested 900MB.